# What are the requirements on the template arguments of std::iterator<...>?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, stl, iterator

I'm trying to write a matrix class where the `begin()` and `end()` member functions are used to iterate over the rows of a matrix. For a nice memory footprint, I decided to hold three member variables:

- the number of rows
- the number of columns
- a data vector of type `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` where `T` is a template argument of my matrix class.

I would like to interoperate with STL algorithms well, therefore I would like my iterators to inherit from

```
namespace std {
    template<
        class Category,
        class T,
        class Distance = std::ptrdiff_t,
        class Pointer = T*,
        class Reference = T&> 
    struct iterator;
}
```

There are a couple of template arguments to this base class `std::iterator<...>` whose default parameters do not really fit my case. The rows are not elements of my matrix, but I need to specify the `Reference` type which is meant to reference a row in my matrix. The same for the `Pointer` type.

How do I go about this? What requirements need to be satisfied for the template parameters of the `std::iterator<...>` template class?

My efforts so far: I implemented a template class named `RowView` which is then taken to be the type for `Reference`, even though it is not a reference type. I figured, this might work, because `std::vector<bool>` does a similar thing. But since [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) did not specify the requirements in detail, I figured, I better ask up front before making a big design mistake. [My source code can be found on github.](https://github.com/ralphtandetzky/render3d/blob/master/mat.hpp) The class in question is the template specialization `template <typename T> class Mat<T,0,0>`.

Comment: The types passed to the iterator template as parameters should be the types you are expecting to have available when you either pass your collection to the `stl` algorithms such as `std::for_each` or range based loop.

Comment: Do you really mean your iterator has a `vector<T>` not a `vector<T>*` ?

Comment: @JSF Iterators will contain a pointer to the first element of the row and the length of the row. Incrementing an iterator means incrementing the first element pointer by the length of the row. I'm also using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of `std::vector<T>`. I just noticed that and changed my question accordingly.

Comment: If you plan to do this more often, do take a look at http://www.amazon.com/Extended-STL-Volume-Collections-Iterators/dp/0321305507.

Comment: How much run time checking do you intend?  I assume `(*it)[c]` will be a reference to column `c` of the current row.  What if `c` is out of range?  (Undefined behavior is the only easy answer to that).  I expect you want `*((*it)+c)` to be the same.  But then it gets real hard for `*it` to be anything smarter than `T*`.  But if `*it` is just `T*` that should answer your original questions.

Comment: @JSF Each iterator basically is a view on a row. Incrementing an iterator means jumping to the next row, i. e. the internal pointer is increased by the number of elements in a row. Runtime checks shall be done with assertions only.

Comment: Yes I understood that requirement on the iterator itself.  I meant the requirement on the thing returned by dereferencing the iterator.

Comment: @JSF The result of derefencing an iterator is basically a view on a row as well, because I want to be able to iterate over a row using `begin()` and `end()` member functions. The idea is to enable range-based for loops of the form `for( auto & row : mat ) for ( auto & x : row ) x = 0;` in order to set all entries of a matrix to zero for example.

Comment: If you are interested in the current source code: Its on github and the current commit is 08ee573. I put a link at the end of my question.